# Can't reference react component from inside callback

Tags: reactjs

In my react component I'm attempting to call the function `emptyCart` once a post request has been completed. However, when I call `the emptyCart` from inside the call back (Denoted in code as SECOND CALL), I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'emptyCart' of undefined`. When I call `emptyCart` from the beginning of the function, however, it works as expected. Sidenote, I don't ever have both calls of `emptyCart` in the code. Why can't I reference my component with `this` from inside the callback?

```
checkout = (order) => {
    this.emptyCart(); //FIRST CALL

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/api',
      data: {
        order:order,
      },
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        this.emptyCart(); //SECOND CALL
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: you're inside a callback function, this is no longer your component

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it worked like that. Do you have a workaround that you recommend?

Comment: yeah i added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is referring to the callback function. A simple fix would be to replace with an arrow function.

```
checkout = (order) => {
this.emptyCart(); //FIRST CALL

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/api',
  data: {
    order:order,
  },
})
.then((response) => {
  this.emptyCart(); //SECOND CALL
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

}

Comment: @PatrickConnors i'd recommend reading up on the this keyword in js, will save you some future headaches